# ASP.NET Get Current Page Object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Trying to get the current page object from a custom class and the only code I can find is:

```
Dim page As UI.Page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, UI.Page)
```

However the result is Nothing (also tried HttpContext.Current.Handler). Is there another reference someone can suggest for me to look at or does someone shed some light on why my code is returning Nothing.

NB: If I use CType instead the exception it returns is:
    Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler' to type 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Dim page As Page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
If page IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Use page instance.
End If
```

Comment: Your  solution is exactly what I have written in my question. You have not provided anything new

Comment: But I'm not getting Nothing as Result.

Comment: Well I am hence why I am asking

Comment: I think I have probably miss lead every body or rather not told the whole truth and nothing but the truth as since researching more I believe my problem is I am using Razor syntax and the Me.Page object is not the same as in Web Forms, so basically what I am doing I have to do it another way but thanks anyhow for your response.

Comment: So you got the solution ? What is the Razor syntax for this ?